# sending random data with Twisted

Tags: python, twisted

I'm trying to create an application that maxes out the user's downstream by continuously sending data.  Is there a variable that tells how many bytes are in the out buffer?  And I say "out buffer," but is there a better term for the data that is being buffered before its sent to the client?  Am I going about this the right way?  It doesn't seem practical to self.transport.write() 100 megabytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way Twisted exposes this information is with a pair of APIs commonly referred to as "producers" and "consumers".  You can find [a document](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/producers.html) about them on the Twisted site.

In your case, a "pull producer" is probably appropriate, since your random data probably isn't coming from an event source, but can be generated on demand.  A rough sketch might look something like this (and hopefully the above linked document will explain why this works):

```
from os import urandom

from zope.interface import implements

from twisted.internet.interfaces import IPullProducer

class RandomProducer(object):
    implements(IPullProducer)

    def __init__(self, consumer):
        self.consumer = consumer


    def resumeProducing(self):
        self.consumer.write(urandom(2 ** 16))


    def stopProducing(self):
        pass
```

So, for example, when a connection is set up, you can register this producer with the transport:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol

class RandomProtocol(Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.transport.registerProducer(RandomProducer(self.transport), False)
```

This will send random data at the client as fast as possible.